# Perguntas feitas como convidado não vão para a conta registrada

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário

Percebi que quando feita uma pergunta como convidado, ela não vai para a conta do usuário depois que ele se registra, mesmo tendo se registrado com o mesmo e-mail que usou para fazer a pergunta como convidado. Seria interessante uma solução para isso.

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1110/

Comment: Resolveu. Obrigado!

Comment: Marquei como duplicata pra tudo mundo achar a solução mais rápido se chegar primeiro aqui. E já avisei o nosso Gerente de Comunidade de que suas contas precisam ser mescladas, ele deve fazer isso no início da semana.

Comment: Já foram mescladas quando enviei a solicitação, mas obrigado.